# Aptana 3 problems with Lion?

Tags: macos, aptana, osx-lion

I am currently trying to get a javascript for a carousel to work in Aptana 3.  The script and implementation info is here: http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm

I couldn't get it to work, the photos won't show up except for one with an error message.  My brother, who is helping me and using Aptana 3 on a mac implemented it with no problems at all.  He then did screen sharing with my comp and did everything the exact same way.  It still didn't work.  He is on Leopard and I am on Lion.  That is the only possible issue we could think of.  Could that be the problem?  Any other possibilities?  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the exact steps you followed, otherwise it's difficult to know what you are encountering. In general, there should be no issues with Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Aptana Studio 3 on Lion for some time now and have not had any issues. As Ingo notes, could you provide some added details to your problem? Specifically, what does not work or what issues are you encountering.

One thing to keep in mind is that a Java runtime does not come included on Lion, which I'm sure you've already been prompted to install. However, you may want to take a look at your AptanaStudio.ini file to make sure you're instructing the IDE to use the right JRE and other info.

1. Open Finder
2. Go to your Applications folder
3. Open the Aptana Studio 3 folder
4. Right-click on the AptanaStudio3 application icon
5. Select "Show Package Contents"
6. Open the "Contents" folder
7. Open the MacOS folder
8. Open the AptanaStudio3.ini file in your favorite text editor

Following are what I believe to be some important and helpful settings in my .ini file, which I only mention this file because it can have an impact on performance:

```
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  256m
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  -vmargs
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
  -Djava.awt.headless=true  
  -Xverify:none
  -XX:+UseParallelGC
  -XX:+AggressiveOpts
  -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
  -XX:PermSize=128m
  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
  -Xmn256m
  -Xss2m
  -Xms256m
  -Xmx768m
```